# Combine two csvs to a third csv: Users and multiple proxyadresses from two domains

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison

CSV1: Columnn 1 is all users.  Columns 2-16 have proxy addresses for each user that vary and some cells are empty.

CSV2: Columnn 1 is all users.  Columns 2-16 have proxy addresses for each user that vary and some cells are empty.

Combine into CSV3...

CSV3: Column 1 would be the same in all CSV's containing all users.  Columns 2-16 would be unique in each row depending on user proxy addresses.  Both domains have different and same proxy addresses for each user.   I want to keep all proxy addresses for each user but remove any duplicates.

See image for example:

[image: Example of Needed CSV Combine Script]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The purpose of this site is to get help with code you've written, not to ask others to produce code for you. With that said, what does your code look like so far? (Also, please do not link to pictures. Use the code formatting tools to insert your desired output as text.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't even know where to start on this. Was searching the site for a similar question but nothing really measured up.  I will try to come back with something useful. My apologies.

Comment: Based on the OPs comment, I'm voting to close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a SQL problem than a powershell problem. I'm feeling a little sick and can't think straight, but you can import each csv into a Common Table Expression, temp table or anything similar in SQL Server or any other database server you want to use and write a query to produce the results.

I've also done something similar in a R class and i bet python will be easier than SQL.

I think i've also read about a join command similar to the SQL inner join. I was looking at it for a problem I had recently. Import each csv into it's own variable and join on the user column and select all the columns from each variable.